# On the asymptotic form of a sum over the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

What is the asymptotic form of the sum

$$\sum_{\rho} \dfrac{x^{\rho}-(x-2)^{\rho}}{\rho}$$

where the summation is over the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function?

By the Prime Number Theorem, we know that this sum is $O(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}})$ for some positive constant $c$, but it seems one can get a much better asymptotic form than this.

Comment: This question would attract more attention if you provided motivation.  Are you trying to study twin primes via the explicit formula?  Why should there be an asymptotic formula in $x$?

Comment: The [Riemann explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula) $x-\psi(x) = x-\sum_{p^k < x} \ln p =  \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} + \ln 2\pi+\frac12 \ln(1-x^{-2})$ means that $\sum_{\rho} \dfrac{x^{\rho}-(x-2)^{\rho}}{\rho} = 2+\psi(x-2)-\psi(x)+\frac12 \ln(\frac{1-x^{-2}}{1-(x-2)^{-2}}) = \mathcal{O}(\ln x)$ and in mean value $=0$ on large intervals for $x$